# Moving the head to the current branch in git

Tags: git, gitlab

I am quite confused why I can't push my changes in the remote branch of my repository
I have this current setup and branches by using `git branch -a`:

```
*(HEAD detached from 008fds4)
develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

Every time I tried to push my commits by `git push origin develop` the terminal displays that `develop does not appear to be a git repository`. Please enlighten me in the current situation of my branch and how can I move the pointer or head to my develop/current branch

Comment: To move `HEAD` to a branch `X`, use `git checkout X`.

Comment: The head is detached. Consider creating a branch where you are? Then you could push it

Comment: A detached HEAD indicates you used `git checkout` on something other than a branch head, such as a tag or a specific commit.

Comment: Problem was fixed by using the checkout command. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your are on a **detached state**.

I suppose you made some modifications to your repository so I suggest you to follow this:

```sh
git stash save
git checkout develop
git stash pop
git add --all
git commit -m "My commit message."
git push
```

Please tell me if it works for you too.

**PS:** `git stash save/pop` prevent you from loosing changes done in the detached state.

Comment: I understand now, for some reason I have already checkout the develop earlier but the head is is still in the detached state, then I checkout develop again then the problem is fixed. Thank you for the additional input, helps a lot. :))

Comment: No, you didn't checkout develop the first time, you checked out 008fds4.